# Как изменить вид поля описания рубрики Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

Как изменить стандартное поле описания рубрики Вордпресс (фото1) на тот что на втором фото?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Поставить SEO-плагин. Скорее всего, Yoast SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как изменить стандартное поле описания рубрики Вордпресс (фото1) на
> тот что на втором фото?

Использовать плагины типа https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-term-description-editor/